# PyCharm wrongly thinks mocked Angular component is the source of a template component

Tags: angular, intellij-idea, pycharm

I have an Angular component called `ChartComponent` with the selector `my-chart`, that is used in several occasions.

In one of these cases, I wanted to test a page that contains a chart, without actually drawing a chart each time. I created a `MockChartComponent` with the same selector `my-chart`. It doesn't do anything, it just sits there in a file somewhere.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-chart',
  template: '<ng-content></ng-content>',
})
export class MockChartComponent {
  @Input() readonly traces: Trace[] = [];
  @Input() readonly layout?: ILayout;
  @Input() readonly status?: Status;
}
```

However, now PyCharm starts complaining in a different file `WidgetComponent`, where I want to use the `ChartComponent`. Even though I import the `ChartModule` in the the `WidgetModule` definition, it still somehow thinks that `my-chart` means the `MockChartComponent` and not the actual chart component. It then throws the error

> Component or directive matching my-chart element is out of the current Angular module's scope

The only way it suggests I can fix it is by declaring a `MockChartComponent` somewhere inside the Angular module's scope, and if I press F12 it points me to the `MockChartComponent` and not the `ChartComponent`. Note that the code works perfectly and compiles just fine, so it's only a problem in the mind of the IDE.

This problem seems to occur everywhere in the codebase, so it's not just a single folder. I could always stop exporting the mock, but I started doing that to keep the code more DRY, so it feels like a step back.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Please feel free to submit an issue in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/web providing a sample project and details about your IDE version.

Comment: related ticket: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-44551